# How to access heroku git over https behind firewalls restricting ssh

Tags: git, https, ssh, heroku

Heroku deployment works like a charm in at my home.

But my office network restricts ssh which blocks the command  "git push heroku master"
Is there a way to use a https url of the heroku git repository to push my app.

Comment: After further digging it seems that heroku does not support git over https. The only workaround is to maintain a copy of the project in GitHub or any other repository which supports https. use this repo to work from locations which do not support ssh. For deployment to heroku clone this app and deploy from a firewall free machine.

Comment: You can also use Tor as a SOCKS proxy for Git.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can push to heroku git only through ssh.

**Update**(per @ryanbrainard comment): 
HTTP Git is now GA https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/5/http_git_now_generally_available

Comment: is that still current?

Comment: omg... took me an hour to figure this out. Haven't had an issue using a global `insteadOf` directive until now. I guess github, bitbucket and all the others i use support https. Why not Heroku?

Comment: Another question: why can't Heroku pull directly from Github?

Comment: Heroku now has beta support for HTTP Git:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git

Comment: HTTP Git is now [GA](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/5/http_git_now_generally_available).

Answer (score 5):

This plugin for heroku toolbelt allows you to push over https:

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push

Comment: is there a similar thing for heroku run?

Comment: That uses the Heroku API to push, which I assume still uses SSH?

Comment: that works for me. I was unable to push throught git (company firewall issue) and with this plugin it works. Great!

Comment: This method is [deprecated](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/586). Please use [HTTP Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793282/how-to-access-heroku-git-over-https-behind-firewalls-restricting-ssh/28521579#28521579).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku now supports GIT over HTTP (this is a beta feature). Check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git. [https://git.heroku.com/{app-name}.git](https://git.heroku.com/%7Bapp-name%7D.git) will be the URL for your repo.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku now has full [HTTP Git support](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/5/http_git_now_generally_available) and is the default option for new apps. If you want to change an existing app from SSH Git to HTTP Git, run:

```
$ heroku git:remote
```

and then push like normal:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

For details, see the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).