# git push heroku master fails by "HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push rails application that shows just "hello, world.".
Then I met an error like below.
I would like to know how to solve this problem.

> $git push heroku master
>   Enumerating objects: 88, done.
>   Counting objects: 100% (88/88), done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (88/88), 22.29 KiB | 1.71 MiB/s, done.
>   Total 88 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   Everything up-to-date

My procedures are below.
1.create rails application like below.
`rails new sample`
2.fix routes and application_controller to show hello, world.
3.change Gemfile.
3-1.declare sqlite3 in development and test group
`gem 'sqlite3'`
3-2.declare pg in production group
`gem 'pg', '0.20.0'`
4.execute `bundle install --without production`
5.execute `git add .`
6.execute `git commit -m "initial commit for heroku"`
7.confirm if it works by `rails s` and access to `localhost:3000`
8.execute `heroku login` and enter id and password.
9.execute `heroku keys:add` and the SSH key is created by this operation.
10.execute `heroku create`
11.execute `git push heroku master` and then I got the error

Each programs' version is below.
* Rails 5.1.6
* heroku/7.14.1 win32-x64 node-v10.9.0

What is this error and how can I avoid this error?
Please tell me if you need more information.

---

I added my gem file below.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
#  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
#  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
# end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'rails_12factor'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: This looks like the same issue. Any luck with answers from that question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449800/error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-400

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried based on the link, but I couldn't...  I use git version 2.18.0.windows, do you think I should use lower version of git?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to both change the remote URL to use the `git:` protocol instead of `https:`, and I also had to create a public key.

To get the current URL:

```sh
git remote get-url heroku
```

Supposing your URL is something like `https://git.heroku.com/your-repo-here.git`, you should use this command to use the `git:` protocol:

```sh
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:your-repo-here.git
```

Create public key:

```sh
heroku keys:add
```

Reference links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059231/679240
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466075/679240

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to increase the buffer to 500MB after navigating to the repository:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
I did it but I got same error...  
Do you have some idea?

Comment: Add this gem gem "rails_12factor" then $bundle install then $git add . $git commit -m "add gem" $git push heroku master let me know if this does work!

Comment: I tried it but the result is same. Is my gem file is wrong?

Comment: heroku keys:add. That's the only reason I know of that could give you permission denied error. $git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:testapp.git and then $heroku keys:add seems to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your help. I recreated application and ssh keys, but I couldn't... It might be something wrong in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, I had this exact same error pushing to Azure. It turned out I'd filled my App Service storage quota.
I deleted a bunch of big files and the problem was solved.