# git push heroku master fails from only 1 terminal(Desktop PC)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rpc

When I push rails application to heroku,
I got the error below.

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.81 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 5 (delta 1)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

When I pushed from another terminal, I could push it.
Each program(OS and git and so on) version and operation is same.
I would like to know the solution to push from the terminal that causes error.

The problem is same as below.
[git push heroku master fails by "HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142214/git-push-heroku-master-fails-by-http-400-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-err)

Do you have any idea to know the cause?
If you need more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your push is failing with the same error message as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449800/error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-400). In the answers there you can find different approaches that could work for you.

Comment: hi, I tried all of approaches in that answers, but I could not solve my problem.
I think the cause is not heroku or git because I could push from another terminal with same setting. Is there any possible that virus check tool disturb some HTTP request?